# time-series analysis in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to analyze a time series. I have a Series indexed with dates, and I would like to split my time series to see e.g. how many $t$ appeared between 16 and 17, how many between 17 and 18, and so on.

How can I do that for minutes, days, weeks, months? Basically I would like to zoom in at different time lengths.

The ideal solution would be something like the .groupby() method, that would allow to easily see how my time series behaves in different periods.

```
                     t
2015-05-27 16:37:08  1
2015-05-27 16:37:12  1
2015-05-27 16:37:48  1
2015-05-27 16:37:49  1
2015-05-27 16:38:00  1
```

Comment: You want to [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample) there is a [section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) on this

Comment: @stochazesthai  hey, it seems that both EdChum and Andrzej have pointed you towards helpful tools...you may wanna give'em a little vote to say thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas provides data structures and data analysis tools for time series and will provide exactly the kind of functionality you are looking for. Look into this page of documentation which focuses on time series:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html